# unable upgrade to ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade by using this steps :

1. Update the system via terminal ("sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade")
2. Run "sudo update-manager -d" (where I hope the Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release ’13.04‘ is available)

But when I did the 1<sup>st</sup> step from terminal, this happened:

```
>Fetched 489 kB in 49s (9,954 B/s)
>Reading package lists... Done
>Reading package lists... Done
>Building dependency tree       
>Reading state information... Done
>You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
>The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>libc6 : Depends: libgcc1 but it is not installed
>         Depends: tzdata but it is not installed
>E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

But when I tried to run "apt-get -f install", I got:

```
>E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I'll really appreciate your suggestion, thanks.

Oh... I forgot to mention that I've tried that too... and the result was:

```
> michael@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 

> [sudo] password for michael:
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        

> Reading state information... Done Correcting dependencies... 

> Done The following extra packages will be installed:   apt-utils debconf
> debconf-i18n dpkg gcc-4.7-base libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12
> libbz2-1.0 libc6 libdb5.1 libgcc1 liblocale-gettext-perl liblzma5
> libselinux1   libstdc++6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
> libtext-wrapi18n-perl perl-base tar zlib1g 
> Suggested packages:  xz-utils debconf-doc debconf-utils whiptail dialog gnome-utils
> libterm-readline-gnu-perl libgtk2-perl libnet-ldap-perl libqtgui4-perl
> libqtcore4-perl apt glibc-doc   locales bzip2 ncompress 

> The following NEW packages will be installed:   apt-utils debconf debconf-i18n dpkg
> libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 libbz2-1.0 libdb5.1 libgcc1
> liblocale-gettext-perl liblzma5 libselinux1 libstdc++6  
> libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl
> perl-base tar zlib1g 

> The following packages will be upgraded:  
> gcc-4.7-base libc6 2 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1
> not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/11.3
> MB of archives. After this operation, 22.3 MB of additional disk space
> will be used. Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
> y 

> debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a
> screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.) debconf: falling
> back to frontend: Readline 

> E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed? debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed:  (Reading database... 479 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to replace libc6:amd64 2.15-0ubuntu20.1 (using .../libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb) ... 
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.) debconf: falling back to frontend:

> Readline Checking for services that may need to be restarted...
> Checking init scripts... Checking for services that may need to be
> restarted... Checking init scripts... Nothing to restart. dpkg: error
> processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  subprocess new pre-installation script returned error
> exit status 2 dpkg: regarding .../libbz2-1.0_1.0.6-4_amd64.deb
> containing libbz2-1.0:amd64, pre-dependency problem:  libbz2-1.0
> pre-depends on multiarch-support   multiarch-support is unpacked, but
> has never been configured.
> 
> dpkg: error processing
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libbz2-1.0_1.0.6-4_amd64.deb (--unpack): 
> pre-dependency problem - not installing libbz2-1.0:amd64 Errors were
> encountered while processing: 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb 
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libbz2-1.0_1.0.6-4_amd64.deb 

> E: Sub-process
> /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Close any graphical applications for package management (software center) and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f`, then try to upgrade. post any error messages.

Comment: Are you sure that you ran the apt-get -f install command with sudo?

Answer (score 1):

#### prepend `sudo`

In your last command, prepend `sudo` to elevate privileges, as the error message suggests. So, run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Either way, your message is about very much base packages not installed at the moment... it sounds very suspicious to me that `tzdata` isn't installed. That would result in all timezone related operations to fail. So, I suspect more is broken on your system, but have a try.